# Pub get has not been run

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I installed the flutter in my windows 11. When I open the new flutter project, after installing the flutter plugins, I got this error 'Pub get has not been run '.
[image]

I also clicked on get dependences and upgrade dependencies. But still getting the error.

Is there any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Android Studio. The message disappears, when I disconnect my phone from my MacBook and plug it in again. You could also try to restart Android Studio, use flutter pub get in your terminal or just press ignore.

Comment: is it okay if I just click on ignore button ?

Comment: If there are no errors in your code because of missing dependencies, clicking ignore should be fine.